# Keep links to deleted posts in their authors' personal area

Tags: feature-request

As I know, users here have links to their deleted posts only for a short time, under "recently deleted posts" on their page. That pages are still accessible by URL after that links are removed. I think that there aren't any cons in keeping those URLs, for authors.

Additional explanations for an automatic quality check: that links would make it comfortable for authors to see their old content, for some reason. Authors may have lots of posts and may not even notice that their post is removed, so, this would help them to control their content.

Comment: [An answer on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406776/constant-points-reduction/406777#406777) with similar content.