# Standardise the order which Review Queues are in across the site

Tags: feature-request, review, sorting

Can the order that the queues appear in on the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review) and in the review drop down be made consistent? Right now the review queue page is ordered by size of queue, while the drop down has a static order resulting in them not having the same order:

[image: Screenshot showing review queue page queue order example]

[image: Screenshot showing static order of review queue drop down]

---

Note this was originally posted as [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363521/) on [New onboarding for review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363485/new-onboarding-for-review-queues) as the review queues are currently being looked at, however I was asked to post it as a new feature request.

Comment: @fedorqui ehhhh somewhat, even if it was made to not reorder in the review page based on queue sizes, I'd still want that list consistent with the review _dropdown_