# How to see Review Queue help boxes again?

Tags: support, review, popups, help

Recently new help boxes for Review Queues were displayed to users. E.g.:

> [image: help box]

The box above is about a specific queue. There is also a main box for queues in general like shown [here](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11496/176217).

After dismissing, such boxes will never appear again for a user.
Is there a way to display them again? In particular I need that to verify translations on ruSO.

Comment: hm. if you just need screenshots I'm sure you can ask nicely and folks from the community can help :D

Comment: I don't have much time now to further dig but here on MSE I can switch the toggle for the suggested-edit review queue back to false by executing this in the console `$.post('/users/toggle-flag/8388608/false', {fkey:StackExchange.options.user.fkey, userid:158100 })` Notice that 158100 is my userid, replace that with your own. The unknown bit is 8388608. I'm not sure if that is per user / per site, so I need a couple of others to keep the dev console open and observe what is being posted on that /users/toggle-flag endpoint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New onboarding for review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363485/new-onboarding-for-review-queues): *"This information can be revisited at any time by clicking “Learn more” under the page header."* - The learn more links show the exact same modals as were originally shown.

Comment: @Nick right, that's probably easier than fiddling with the JavaScript. It doesn't work for the [general information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTgCK.png) though, which is also what αλεχολυτ asked about.

Comment: @Glorfindel, good spot, I only tested it for a few queues, didn't think to do it for general info. Seems more like a defect to me that it doesn't and that clicking learn more on the "all queues" page should show it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way, which as @Nick noted is [in the announcement itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363485/new-onboarding-for-review-queues?noredirect=1&lq=1), is to use the 'Learn more' link in the queue:

[image]

That doesn't work for the general review information, though. As @rene discovered, it's possible to reset the popups through fiddling a bit with the site's JavaScript. In the snippet below, replace `[USER_ID]` with your user ID on that site, and `[FLAG_ID]` with the ID of the flag, which can be found in the following table:

| Review Queue | Flag ID | Bit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [General information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTgCK.png) | 32768 | 15 |
| First Posts | 131072 | 17 |
| Late Answers | 262144 | 18 |
| Close Votes | 524288 | 19 |
| Reopen Votes | 1048576 | 20 |
| Triage | 2097152 | 21 |
| Help & Improvement | 4194304 | 22 |
| Suggested Edits | 8388608 | 23 |
| Low Quality Posts | 16777216 | 24 |

You can also sum flag IDs to reset multiple flags at once; `33554431` will reset all popups (but this include lower bits as well; see below what those flags are for; for just the review queues, the target number is `33456128`).

```js
$.post('/users/toggle-flag/[FLAG_ID]/false',
  {fkey:StackExchange.options.user.fkey, userid:[USER_ID] })
```

Execute the JavaScript in your browser console and you should see the popup(s) again.

@rene did an excellent job (again) for finding all flags; just execute `StackOverflow.Models.UserFlags` in your browser console and it'll show the equivalent of this table:

| Flag ID | Flag Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TeamGuide |
| 2 | DismissMarkdownEditorHelp |
| 4 | HideLeftNavigation |
| 8 | DismissMentionsCallout |
| 16 | DismissQuestionPageProductBanner |
| 32 | DismissWelcomeModal |
| 64 | DismissCloseReopenPrivilegePopover |
| 128 | DismissCloseReopenPrivilegeExplanationModal |
| 256 | DismissPostReactionIntroPopover |
| 512 | DismissFollowQuestionIntroPopover |
| 1024 | DismissClosedEditModal |
| 2048 | DismissModalForCompletedEditOnClosedQuestion |
| 4096 | DismissAddAdminNotice |
| 8192 | ShowReviewQueueNotice |
| 16384 | ReviewQueueNoticeIsForCampaign |
| 32768 | DismissReviewOnboarding |
| 65536 | ShowNewReviewerOnboarding |
| 131072 | DismissModalForFirstPostQueue |
| 262144 | DismissModalForLateAnswerQueue |
| 524288 | DismissModalForCloseVoteQueue |
| 1048576 | DismissModalForReopenVoteQueue |
| 2097152 | DismissModalForTriageQueue |
| 4194304 | DismissModalForHelperQueue |
| 8388608 | DismissModalForSuggestedEditQueue |
| 16777216 | DismissModalForLowQualityPostQueue |
| 1073741824 | DisableSideNav |

Comment: Okay, if you flip all flags to false, do you still have a diamond on Chess.se?

Comment: That would be interesting. Perhaps you could try flipping all flags to true and check if you'd become one?

Comment: There is probably a thin-line between a honest experiment and abuse. Maybe wait for a dev to confirm how much damage we can do here ...

Comment: I've found them all: StackOverflow.Models.UserFlags in the console is the Enum that is used.

Comment: @rene sadly, no `DisableModeratorPrivileges`...

Comment: Source is in http://dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js search for `// StackOverflow.Models.UserFlags` but that part is generated based on the header found a few lines above that model definition

Comment: There are still bits unaccounted for ;)  Who knows what 536.870.912 is for ...