# Change "reopen" to "leave open" in Close Votes queue

Tags: bug, review, help-center

It seems that "reopen" should be changed to "leave open" in Close Votes queue tips box:

> [image: Close votes queue]

since there's no option as "Reopen" but "Leave open" has.

Comment: I have suggested something very similar already: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364143/295232